# How to read notifications correctly on Android

Tags: java, android, notifications, whatsapp

I am developing an App for read notifications all my code work great, but have two problems. I use this code for read notifications:

```html
   String pack = sbn.getPackageName();
        String ticker ="";
        if(sbn.getNotification().tickerText !=null) {
            ticker = sbn.getNotification().tickerText.toString();
        }
        Bundle extras = sbn.getNotification().extras;
        String title = extras.getString("android.title");


        //String text = extras.getCharSequence("android.text").toString();
         String text = null;
        if (extras.getCharSequence("android.text") != null) {
            text =(String) extras.getCharSequence("android.text");
        }
        if (text == null) {
// for whatsapp on kitkat second whats app text
// will be null
            if (extras.get("android.textLines") != null) {
                CharSequence[] charText = (CharSequence[]) extras
                        .get("android.textLines");
                if (charText.length > 0) {
                    text = charText[charText.length - 1].toString();
                }
            }
        }
```

The code works, but the problem is with WhatsApp, when I receive more than one message I get the following structure.

```
Title: NameUser
Text: Hi, how are you?  <---- This is ok!
```

but the second message I get

```
Title: NameUser
Text : Hi again! <--- This is ok;

Title: NameUser
Text: 2 New messages <---- Agggr that is wrong!!!!!
```

How can avoid the "2 New messages"??

And the second question is Can I get images send via whatsapp? For the moment I only get the following structure.

```
Title: NameUser
Text: Image
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just Solved thanks!

Comment: how did you solve it ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can influence (from your app) what notifications are sent by some other app's server to your phone.

Comment: I only want avoid the "2 new messages" text

Comment: If your app isn't the one sending that notification, then you have NO WAY of avoiding it. Of course, you can set up a filter to filter out every "X new messages" notifications, but you cannot guarantee that the text of the notification will remain the same over time. For example, WhatsApp can decide to change to text to "You received X messages" and your app will not be able to filter them out anymore. Imagine if multiple versions of the WhatsApp application all used different notification texts - you would have to prepare your app to handle all of them.